# Making a Color Screen in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, colors, filter, screen

So, I've got a collection of objects that I've made in openGL. They each have their own colors, and some of them have textures applied to them. What I want to do is stop certain colors from reaching the screen, but still be able to change it. Is there a way to cherry-pick which colors actually get painted?

I've tried putting a translucent plane in front of the camera, but it doesn't stop other colors from getting through- rather, it just blends with them.

Ideally, this is how it would work:

> red object + red screen = red object
>
> blue object + red screen = gray/black/white object
>
> purple object + red screen = red object

-EDIT-

To clarify what I'm trying to get this to do: I want to leave the RGB values of all my objects the same. Before they are painted onto the screen, though, I want to 'zero' some of the color values without making any actual changes to the object.

So an object with RGB [255,150,200] going through a red filter would be painted as if it had the RGB value [255,0,0], a green filter [0,150,0], and a blue filter [0,0,200].

Comment: The description for `how it would work...` seems pretty vague. Can you express this as a function of, say, source and destination RGB(A)?

Comment: I've edited the question with some RGB value examples. Hopefully that helps explain my question.

Comment: This should be a rather straightforward task for a fragment shader.

Comment: From what I can tell, a fragment shader's just what I need to get pixel data about what's being drawn. As for actually CHANGING the individual color values of the things I get and then sending them back? I can't seem to find anything. Do you have anywhere you could point me?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for glColorMask?

See this answer: [Render into a color channels without affecting other channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569739/render-into-a-color-channels-without-affecting-other-channels)

I'm not clear on your problem, but this will mask out/in selected colour channels: R, G, B or A

---

Given this

> So an object with RGB [255,150,200] going through a red filter would be painted as if it had the RGB value [255,0,0], a green filter [0,150,0], and a blue filter [0,0,200]

glColorMask will work.

```
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE);
drawMyRedFilteredStuff();
// Return open gl state back to normal function
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
```

If you only need to filter by red, green, blue or alpha then this is exactly what you are looking for.

Am I still not getting what you are trying to do?

Comment: While the effect glColorMask gives is cool, it's not quite what I want. It's just keeping certain color channels from being edited until they are enabled. What I need is to stop opengl to stop putting certain colors onto the screen. I need to _eliminate_ two of the RGB components of any number of objects in my scene...

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be best handled by a fragment shader. If the 'filter' is a constant value, you can set it as a uniform, e.g.,

```
uniform vec3 filter_rgb;
in vec3 src_rgb;

out vec4 dst_rgba;

void main (void)
{
    dst_rgba = vec4(min(filter_rgb, src_rgb), 1.0);
}
```

So if any of the filter components are set to zero, the corresponding output component will be zero also. Depending on the behaviour you want, a `clamp` function may be a more useful choice of builtin than the `min` function.

Comment: From what I understand about shaders, I'm pretty sure this is what I need. Do you think you could point me to (or give me yourself) an explanation on how to implement something like this in the body of a program? Like if I wanted the filter to _only_ paint the red component of the fragment, what would I do to your example?